# how to declare and initialize global arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, global

In my html code, I need a global array which I use throughout my application. How to create and initialize global array variable in javascript..

Comment: `window.arrayname = [];`, or `var arrayname = [];` (in the global scope).

Comment: I want to declare that global array in function, i tried it without using var keyword, but it doesn't read that variable..

Comment: Are you sure the array is initialized before you try to read from it?

Comment: yeah, i initialized it before reading using names = new Array();

Comment: What code do you currently have?

Answer (score 11):

You  can do it several ways :
In the global scope :

```
var arr = [];
```

Binding the array to the global namespace:

```
window.arr = [];
```

or, for running the code in other environments, where the global object is not necessarily called `window`:

```
(function(global){
    global.arr = [];
})(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the browser, you can attach objects to the global scope using the window object:

```
window.myArray = ["foo", "bar"];
```

In Node.js, you can access the global scope using the `global` object.

Comment: No need to throw in `Node.js`. Considering the question, the OP is a novice JavaScript programmer.

Comment: Don't encourage it. Implicit variable declaration makes code less readable -> more likely to fail. In [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Strict_mode), implicit variable declaration is forbidden, and a ReferenceError is thrown.

Comment: _Implicit variable declaration_ is what? There's no such thing, you probably mean global variable. There's no reason why would that increase chances of fail, it's all authors responsibility. It's not the best practice around, but in many cases it works pretty well, like when you want to provide some JSON data on the HTML page for scripts, to avoid extra XHR.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this to declare an array in global scope :

```js
let arr = [];
```

Comment: Welcome! This answer does not add any to the already given answer by gion_13 IMHO.